# StateMachine get Object for Test

Tags: state-machine, spring-statemachine

StateMachineJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean get State machine from it.
I am trying to create a entire test case for state machine for that I am trying to generate StateMachine Object from model factory but its not giving an object. Please suggest .

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = EndorsementOrchestration.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class SimpleStateMachineConfigurationTest extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
    @Autowired
    private StateRepository<? extends RepositoryState> stateRepository;
    @Autowired
    private TransitionRepository<? extends RepositoryTransition> transitionRepository;

    @Bean
    public StateMachineJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean() {
        StateMachineJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factoryBean = new StateMachineJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setResources(new Resource[]{new ClassPathResource("data.json")});
        return factoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineModelFactory<String, String> modelFactory() {
        RepositoryStateMachineModelFactory factory = new RepositoryStateMachineModelFactory(stateRepository, transitionRepository);
        return factory;
    }

    @Test
    void so() throws Exception {
        StateMachineModel<String, String> stateMachine1 = modelFactory().build();
        stateMachine1.getStatesData();
        System.out.println("just");
    }

}
```